# Prove that for all positive $x,y,z$, $\small\left(2e^x+\dfrac{2}{e^x}\right)\left(2e^y+\dfrac{2}{e^y}\right)\left(2e^z+\dfrac{2}{e^z}\right) \geq 64$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Prove that for all positive $x,y,z$, $\left(2e^x+\dfrac{2}{e^x}\right)\left(2e^y+\dfrac{2}{e^y}\right)\left(2e^z+\dfrac{2}{e^z}\right) \geq 64$

I dont have that much experience with inequalities but I know I can rewrite $64 $ as $4^3$

So here is my approach, if I can maybe prove that $\left(2e^x+\dfrac{2}{e^x}\right) \geq4$ as well for $y,z$ and then maybe I can prove it is greater than 64. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

For all $a>0$, $a^2-2a+1=(a-1)^2\ge 0$, so $a^2+1\ge 2a$, so $a+\frac{1}{a}\ge 2$. Now take $a$ to be $e^x,e^y,e^z$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u = e^x$.  Then if $x > 0$, then $u > e^0 = 1$, and consider $$u + u^{-1} - 2 = u - 2u^{-1/2}u^{1/2} + u^{-1} = (u^{1/2} - u^{-1/2})^2 \ge 0.$$  The first equality is because $u^{-1/2}u^{1/2} = 1$, and the inequality is due to the fact that the square of a real number is never negative.  Consequently, $$u+u^{-1} \ge 2,$$ from which it follows that $$2\left(e^x + e^{-x}\right) \ge 4,$$ and the result is proven.